# Ring Flip of glucose

Tags: carbohydrates, cyclohexane, ring-strain

I have recently read about **mutarotation** of glucose specifically

I am familiar with how cyclic structures like **substituted cyclo-hexanes** exist in an equilibrium of **both their chair conformers**.

The thing is, for mutarotation, the interconversion takes place via an open-chain form, which is I think supported by enough experimental evidence like the specific rotation of equilibrium mixture.

[image]

But, can ring flip take place the old-school way, that is without opening the ring in a solvent like ***CCl4 or Benzene***

Or is the ring too strained to cross the energy barrier?

Comment: Cyclohexane does not require change of chiral centers to change conformation. R stays R and S stays S. For mutatotation, you need a change in a chiral center, which requires a bond to break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

- Experiment with a model kit ([example](https://www.maruzen.info/hgs/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=653)) and recognize changing conformers *only* is about wiggling/rotating bonds which may be gradual in many tiny steps.
- The transition from one isomer to an other (e.g., $\alpha{} \rightarrow \beta{}$-glucose) is binary like using a light switch; instead of on/off, it is either (*R*), or (*S*) – or, in case of double bonds, either (*E*), or (*Z*).  This requires *breaking* existing/creating new bonds.  Solvent, temperature, radiation, pressure, reagents, catalysts may affect the energetic barrier to achieve this, but normally this change requires surpassing a much higher energetic barrier than the typical rotation around a $\ce{C-C}$ single bond.

While simplified,* this description *often* is sufficient for everyday like chemistry, including your example about the inversion/mutarotation of glucose dissolved in water.  In benzene or $\ce{CCl4}$, this reaction however probably will proceed at a much lower rate of conversion than in water because the assumed mechanism includes steps of protonation/deprotonation and these two solvents are not as good "proton shuttles" (as a Bronsted acid/base) as is water.

From a practical perspective, either form of glucose will not dissolve well in benzene, or $\ce{CCl4}$.  Mutarotation however is observed for many sugars e.g., permethylated glucose in benzene and surfactants (e.g., described by Fendler *et al.*), or pyridone (e.g., Rony) and still of interest today (e.g., Dujardin *et al.*).

*) My answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152911/could-gaussian-or-spartan-software-determine-stereoisomers-from-conformational-l/152916#152916) points to some exceptions from this simplification.

**References**

Fendler, E. J.; Fendler, J. H.; Medary, R. T.; Woods, V. A. Catalysis by reversed micelles in non-polar solvents : mutarotation of 2,3,4,6-tetramethyl-α-D-glucose in benzene. *J. Chem. Soc. D* **1971**, 1497–1497; [doi 10.1039/C29710001497](https://doi.org/10.1039/C29710001497).

Rony, P. R. Polyfunctional catalysis. I. Activation parameters for the mutarotation of tetramethyl-D-glucose in benzene. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1968**, *90*, 2824–2831; [doi 10.1021/ja01013a018](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01013a018).

Dujardin, N.; Dudognon, E.; Willart, J.-F.;  Hédoux, A. H; Guinet, Y.; Paccou, L.; Descamps, M. Solid State Mutarotation of Glucose. *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2011**, *115*, 1698–1705; [doi 10.1021/jp109382j](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp109382j).